# book cover with tikz + Optex

Tags: tikz-pgf, bookcover, optex

I would like a frame around the page, but somehow the right and bottom frames don't appear. (Any more elegant overall solutions, with Tikz or otherwise, are welcome, too.)

```
\load[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc,positioning}

\fontfam[Minion]
\topglue 0pt plus 1fill
\nopagenumbers
\margins/1 a4 (2,2,2,2)cm


\setbox0\hbox {\typoscale[3000/3000] \setletterspace{10}\caps\rm  ~~~A Wonderful Title~~~}
\newdimen\bd
\bd=\wd0

%\_overfullrule=0pt


\pgbackground={\noindent\tikzpicture
\node (titulo) at (current page.center) {\box0};
\node[below=of titulo] {\typoscale[2000/2000]\it John Doe};
\node[below= 9cm of titulo] {\typoscale[1500/1500]\caps\rm Myself Editions, Inc.};
\draw (current page.center)  node[draw,red,line width=5pt,minimum height=22cm,minimum width=\dimexpr\bd+0.8cm] {};
\draw (current page.center) node[minimum height=24cm,minimum width=\dimexpr\bd+2.3cm,draw,line width=8pt,red] {};
\draw[line width=8pt,black] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\endtikzpicture}



\vfill \eject


\pgbackground={}
\pageno=1

\lipsum[1]


\bye
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Optex but the `current page` node needs `remember picture` as an option to the tikzpicture, most likely also `overlay`: `\tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]`. Whether this works with Optex, I don't know.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, whether I use `remember picture` or not, it's the same.

Comment: Seems that it's too much of a worthless hassle to worry about book covers and drawing using commands. Any word processor drawing app and, of course, InDesign can do that in a few minutes. You include the resulting pdf, and voilà, `\pgbackground` does the rest.

Comment: I don't understand TikZ (and I am able to do your picture using `\frame` in `\frame` in `\frame` without TikZ), but I noticed at page 260 of TikZ manual an example with the`current page.center` and this example includes `\tikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]`. If I added these parameters to your example then your picture is centered (after second OpTeX run). Moreover, you need not to use `\pgbackground`.